# How to install Android Studio on Windows 10 Home Edition running AMD Processor?

Tags: android, react-native, windows-10, virtual-environment, amd-processor

I am runnning AMD processor on Windows machine and I get the following error when trying to install **Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver** for Android Studio:

[image: image description]

However, Microsoft's official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) tells me that my Operating System - Windows 10 Home Edition doesn't support this Hyper-V installation:

> [image]

Is Hyper-V a virtual environment? If so, what are other alternatives to Hyper-V so that I can develop phone applications?
My goal is be able to use Android Studio & React-Native on my computer to build and run apps. So I'm looking for an alternative option than upgrade my Windows 10 Home edition. Is there work around by using Azure or Dock?